# get dynamic input value using ng-model in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have list of product and from each product use will add some quantity which I need in my controller.

- the product list is not fix it might be 10 product (10 input box for qty) or may 100 product.

In HTML this is my code

```
<div class="col m3" ng-repeat="product in productlist" ng-cloak>

  <h6 style="font-size:14px;">{{ product.product_name }}</h6>
  <input ng-modal="qty[product.pid]" placeholder="Qty" type="number"> 

  <button class="btn-flat" ng-click="addQty(product.pid)">ADD</button>
</div>
```

I am not understanding how I can get this value along with pid in controller

```
// ORDER ADD   
$scope.addQty = function (pid) {

    //$scope.qty = {};
    //$scope.product = $scope.productlist;  

    console.log($scope.qty[pid]);  

    var getlistURL = $scope.baseURL+$scope.uri.uri_1+"/"+$scope.uri.uri_2+"/ng_add_to_cart/"+pid+"/";

    $http.post(getlistURL).
    success(function(data, status) {

        if(data.length != 0) {
            $scope.stockmovement = data;    
            $('#showStockMovement').modal('open');
        } 
    });
};
```

Thanks

Comment: typo error it should be `ng-model` not `ng-modal`

Comment: Nop still not working.. I am not getting value in controller..

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my answer

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    
 
 //$scope.productlist = [];
 $scope.modelData = {};
 $scope.productlist = {
  0:{"pid" : 1,
  "product_name" : "Laptop",
  
  },
  1:{"pid" : 2,
  "product_name" : "Computer",
  
  },
  2:{"pid" : 3,
  "product_name" : "Camera",
  
  },
  3:{"pid" : 4,
  "product_name" : "Tv",
  
  }
 }
 $scope.addQty = function(pid){
 alert(pid)
 console.log($scope.modelData[pid])
 }
  });
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  
  <title>Angular-Google-Charts Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="modal" style="background-color: #EDEEF1;" ng-controller="myController">
        <div class="col m3" ng-repeat="product in productlist" ng-cloak>

   <h6 style="font-size:14px;">{{ product.product_name }}</h6>
   <input ng-model="modelData[product.pid]" placeholder="Qty" type="number"> 

   <button class="btn-flat" ng-click="addQty(product.pid)">ADD</button>
  </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please check this demo. Let me know if it works!

Comment: Can you please provide a plunker if possible?

Comment: Check now @Prashant Fepale

Answer (score 0):

Here you should not try to pass just id like you did in the code. Instead of that, pass the entire object to the function and when you will manipulate its attributes, it will get effect on the page at the same time. This is how you can get real time effect of quantity change.

So modify the argument of the **addQty** function.

```
 <div class="col m3" ng-repeat="product in productlist" ng-cloak>
   <h6 style="font-size:14px;">{{ product.product_name }}</h6>
   <input ng-modal="qty[product.pid]" placeholder="Qty" type="number"> 
   <button class="btn-flat" ng-click="addQty(product)">ADD</button>
 </div>
```

Then you can access any attribute of the product object in the function. Like written below:

```
// ORDER ADD   
$scope.addQty = function (product) {

    //$scope.qty = {};
    //$scope.product = $scope.productlist;  

    console.log(product.pid);  

    var getlistURL = $scope.baseURL+$scope.uri.uri_1+"/"+$scope.uri.uri_2+"/ng_add_to_cart/"+product.pid+"/";

    $http.post(getlistURL).
    success(function(data, status) {

        if(data.length != 0) {
            $scope.stockmovement = data;    
            $('#showStockMovement').modal('open');
        } 
    });
};
```

This is your solution.

Comment: `// ORDER ADD   
   $scope.addQty = function (pid) {

  //$scope.qty = {};
    //$scope.qty = $scope.productlist; 

  console.log(product.pid);  

  var getlistURL = $scope.baseURL+$scope.uri.uri_1+"/"+$scope.uri.uri_2+"/ng_add_to_cart/"+pid+"/";
     
     $http.post(getlistURL).
  success(function(data, status) {

   if(data.length != 0) {
    $scope.stockmovement = data; 
    $('#showStockMovement').modal('open');
   } 
  });
 }; `

Comment: This is just a function. I want to see the controller of Angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

Deducing from the limited information that is available, my guess is that you haven't initialized your array `qty`.
You should initialize your `qty` array to a length equal to the length of your `productlist`, with all initial values set to 0.

```
$scope.qty = [];
var initQty = function(){
for(var i = 0;i<$scope.productlist.length;i++){
    $scope.qty[i]=0;
}
}();
```

Apart from that, your code looks fine after changing the `ng-modal` to `ng-model`, as already suggested by other folks.

Answer (score 0):

if your productlist is of this type.

```
$scope.productlist = 
    [
    {product_name: "Soap",  pid: 25},
    {product_name: "Bag",   pid: 100}
];
```

Use this code

```
<div class="col m3" ng-repeat="product in productlist">
   {{ product.product_name }}
   <input ng-model="product.pid" placeholder="Qty" type="number"> 
   <button class="btn-flat" ng-click="addQty(product)">ADD</button>
 </div>
```

if you want to enter pid manually and get value in controller and don't want to attach with productlist

```
 <div class="col m3" ng-repeat="product in productlist">
   {{ product.product_name }}
   <input ng-model="qty" placeholder="Qty" type="number"> 
   <button class="btn-flat" ng-click="addQty(qty)">ADD</button>
 </div>
```

and in your code type error is there change "ng-modal" to "ng-model"

seems like you want only the qty number so better try second one

Answer (score 0):

https://plnkr.co/edit/gBLx1iIWL4x84ldtQAtF?p=preview

Here is a working plunker.. Changes I made are only 2 ng-model instead of ng-modal and initialised qty as object so now your quantities will be stored with pid as key of the object and qty as value of the object

for example :-

```
{ "1" : 6, "2" :12}
```

so you can basically have as many products you want with this

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat is an isolated scope , so model variables created in ng-repeat are not accessible in controller.

To solve your requirement we can follow two approaches

1.you can pass product id and quantity as two arguments and retrieve that in a function

```
 <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div class="col m3" ng-repeat="product in productlist" ng-cloak>

   <h6 style="font-size:14px;">{{ product.product_name }}</h6>
   <input ng-model="qty" placeholder="Qty" type="number"> 

   <button class="btn-flat" ng-click="addQty(product.id,qty)">ADD</button>

  </div>`
```

but this approach we dont have track of all products and all quantities, please check below plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/zAz6FVgazOH4NWYpKb4u?p=preview

2.Second approch is following ControllerAs concepts , instead of using $scope we use ControllerAs to get values inside controller model.

```
    <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as ctl">
  <div class="col m3" ng-repeat="product in ctl.productlist" ng-cloak>

   <h6 style="font-size:14px;">{{ product.product_name }}</h6>
   <input ng-model="ctl.qty[product.id]" placeholder="Qty" type="number"> 

   <button class="btn-flat" ng-click="ctl.addQty(product.id)">ADD</button>

  </div>

  {{ctl.qty}}
```

In this approach we can build an object called qty where we can keep track of all products and quantities

Please check below plunker for this approach
https://plnkr.co/edit/QIVGt8MCdPRAhHaqVA64?p=preview

Hope this meets your requirement